# Convert tty terminal output to plain text

Tags: console, tty, wine

I want to capture the text output of windows console app I run with `wineconsole --backend=curses ...`.

The app itself just uses boring stdio. Unfortunately, wine does a lot of escaping of the output, such that it is useless when redirecting it to a file.

`wineconsole` does use the `TERM` environment variable - e.g. it behaves a little different when I set `TERM=vt100` or `TERM=linux`.

I guess, I am looking for a very basic `TERM` where no screen clearing is done at all.

Or a tool that emulates a tty and translates the output into normal text.

Comment: Hmm, if wine is indeed doing something to the output, could you instead run the application under `script(1)` or `autoexpect` and save the raw output that way, instead of through wine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try setting `TERM=dumb`, which might work — if `wineconsole` does not insist on making a full-screen display.

If not, as noted, `script` is part of the solution.  That lets you run your program, transparently collecting all of the data sent to the screen in a text file.

Making sense of it is the rest of the solution.  If `wineconsole` simply writes left-to-right / top-to-bottom, it is possible to filter out the escapes (including colors) and get some useful plain text.  If it jumps around the screen, showing forms, etc., you will not be able to do this very well.  But filtering out the escapes (even partially) is often better than nothing.

The topic of filtering out escape sequences comes up occasionally, e.g., [Can I programmatically “burn in” ANSI control codes to a file using unix utils?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269278/can-i-programmatically-burn-in-ansi-control-codes-to-a-file-using-unix-utils)

Further reading:

- [3.8. Text mode programs (CUI: Console User Interface)](https://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/cui-programs) *Wine User Guide*
- [script2log](http://invisible-island.net/scripts/readme.html#item:script2log) *Strips ANSI escape sequences and reduces backspace/overstrikes.*

Comment: wine doesn't like `TERM=dump` - with that most output is gone. My app just writes left to right/top to bottom. Thus, I'll try to call `wineconsole` via `script` and post-process the result.