# How to make Vim interpret CR characters as in terminal (overwrite the current line)

Tags: vim

A bit of context: I use a progress bar (in particular [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/)) to monitor the progress of my script which is executing on a remote machine, accessed through ssh. As long I have the ability to access the screen session where the script is running, everything is fine.

Sometimes I cannot use screen (specifically, during a batch job ran with [slurm](https://slurm.schedmd.com/)), so I end up redirecting the output of my script to a file. I have found three options in this case:

1. `tail -f file`: the progress bar is displayed correctly and updated as the file is updated, but only shows the last n lines and I cannot search interactively.
2. `less +F -r file`: the progress bar is displayed correctly, but not updated as the file changes (at least not until a new line is written).
3. `vim file`: this would be my preferred method, but the progress bar is messed up, CR characters are shown as `^M`. This is expected, I guess, and I can execute `:%s/\r/\r/g` to see the progress bar "unrolled" on multiple lines, which is better than the default situation, yet not great.

Is there a way to make Vim interpret a CR as "overwrite the current line" as it happens in terminals? If this is not possible, I think it might be done with a function to execute manually whenever I fancy: I do not know vimscript though, so a help would be great.

[EDIT]
I tried some methods suggested here [Convert tty terminal output to plain text](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274530/convert-tty-terminal-output-to-plain-text/274544#274544), and here [Can I programmatically "burn in" ANSI control codes to a file using unix utils?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269278/can-i-programmatically-burn-in-ansi-control-codes-to-a-file-using-unix-utils), as suggested in comments, but I had no luck.

Comment: See for example [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274530/convert-tty-terminal-output-to-plain-text/274544#274544)