# Accessing xterm native window using GUI

Tags: bluetooth

Your question has been identified as a possible duplicate of another question. If the answers there do not address your problem, please edit to explain in detail the parts of your question that are unique.

See pending request for updating original post

Since this is not strictly Linux problem , I am very reluctant to post this here.
Would appreciate not to get banned and blocked from more legitimate posts because of that.
Just ignore the post if it does not fit rules.

I like to use xterm to run system command - in my case "bluetoothctl"  - and be able to process its output in C++ application.

It is my understanding the Xterm  outputs to "native window" - it is fully visible in
my application, however, I cannot figure out HOW to actually access it in code.

In not so technical terms - how do I make a copy of xterm "native window " to a object of my choice in my application. I know how to retrieve the xterm  output from a file,
but such file contains control characters and I would prefer not to edit them out - but I have done that.

I like to be able to "drag and drop" from one "native xterm window" to another.

Comment: This answers your question: [Convert tty terminal output to plain text](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274530/convert-tty-terminal-output-to-plain-text).  There are several possible duplicates.

Comment: If you only want to grab output of the command you don't have to run xterm and run a command in it, every general purpose programming language can do this

Comment: I am not familiar with customs at this forum , hence  I am not sure if the following won't be considered offensive and I'll get banned for it. . I asked for help resolving an issue with xterm and I get "do this, do that INSTEAD ". When I spend my time explaining specific issues with specific  task I expect an answer for specific issue  with specific conditions.In other words - objective of my post was not to find alternative to accomplish the task.

Comment: If OK with posting rules - I would like to edit my post. Please somebody confirm - I do not want to get banned for not following rules.

Answer (score 0):

I'd capture the output using [`script`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html), and filter out the color escape sequences using [`script2log`](https://invisible-island.net/scripts/readme.html#item:script2log) (since `bluetoothctl`'s use of those is hard-coded).